# Steps to derive a weak formulation (streamline diffusion)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm studing ADR equations and now the book I'm following (*Quarteroni - Numerical models for differential problems*) wants to add *artificial diffusion* in a 2-D problem.

This corresponds to add the term $-Q h \Delta u$ to the initial problem ($Q>0$, $h$ is the step size), and it's called *upwind artificial diffusion*. The additional diffusion that one has to introduce must be introduced only in the direction of the field $\mathbf{b}$, not in all directions.

As example, the book consider the problem:

> \begin{align}
>  - \mu \Delta u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=f \quad \text{in } \Omega, \quad u=0 \text{ in } \partial \Omega \end{align}
>
> and here $\mathbf{b}=[1,0]^T$
>
> So the artificial diffusion term one was to introduce is
>
> \begin{align}
>  -Q h \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \text{ and not } -Q h (\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}  + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial
>  y^2}) \end{align}

And up to now I have no problem. The problem is the following.

More generally, we can add the following *stabilization term*

\begin{align}
-Qh \text{div}[(\mathbf{b} \cdot \nabla u)\mathbf{b}]=-Qh \text{div}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{b}} \mathbf{b}) \quad (\star)
\end{align}

In the weak formulation, the latter yields the following term

\begin{align}
b(u,v)=Qh (\mathbf{b} \cdot \nabla u, \mathbf{b} \cdot \nabla u)
\end{align}

**How to get the above b(u,v) term?**

After this step, it's everything okay, it just states the final weak formulation

> Then, the resulting discrete problem, called **streamline diffusion**,
>   becomes
>
> \begin{align} \text{find } u_h \in V_h: a_h(u_h,v_h)=(f,v_h) \quad
>  \forall v_h \in V_h \end{align}
>
> where $a_h(u_h,v_h)=a(u_h,v_h)+b_h(u_h,v_h)$

---

My main problem is that I can't understand how to pass from ($\star$) to the $b(u,v)$. For sure I have to multiply $\star$ with a test function $v$ and the integrate as usual, i.e. (I drop $Q,h$ since are just constants)

\begin{align}
\text{div}[(\mathbf{b} \cdot \nabla u)\mathbf{b}] v
\end{align}

But from there I don't know how to move.

Comment: What does $(\cdot,\cdot)$ means in first equation after $(\star)$?

Comment: I think it's the scalar product in $L^2$ which one has doing the weak formulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating by parts and using the divergence theorem, we can write
\begin{align}
(\operatorname{div}[(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla u)\mathbf{b}],v) 
    &= \int_\Omega\operatorname{div}[(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla u)\mathbf{b}]v 
        dx = \\
    &= \int_\Omega\operatorname{div}[(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla u)\mathbf{b}v] 
        dx 
    - \int_\Omega(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla u)(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla v)dx = \\
    &= \int_{\partial\Omega}(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla u)\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf
        {n}vdx
    -(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla u,\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla v)
\end{align}
and I suppose the boundary integral vanishes.

In more detail:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{div}[(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla u)\mathbf{b}]v 
    &= \left[\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\sum_{j= 1}^3
        b_j\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}\right)b_i\right]v = \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\sum_{j=1}^3b_j\frac{ 
        \partial u}{\partial x_j}b_iv\right) 
    - \sum_{j=1}^3b_j\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}\sum_{i=1}^3\frac 
        {\partial }{\partial x_i}b_iv = \\
    &= \operatorname{div}[(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla u)\mathbf{b}v] 
    - ( \mathbf { b }\cdot\nabla u)(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla v)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, what I have to understand is the identity you used in order to bring the test function $v$ inside the divergence. The rest is clear !

Comment: @VoB it is simply integration by parts: to see, write explicitly divergence, gradient and inner product

Comment: Sorry, I mean: why you write $ \operatorname{div}[(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla u)\mathbf{b}]v=\operatorname{div}[(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla u)\mathbf{b}v] - (\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla u)(\mathbf{b}\cdot\nabla v)$  in the step after the first integral? Then you apply divergence theorem and it's everything okay.
It seems more like a product rule, not a integration by parts.

Comment: @VoB: integration by part is nothing else than chain rule used in reverse, see the edited answer

Comment: Ok, now everything it's clear! Many thanks @enzotib !

Comment: @enzotib Is it possible to get the same result by using the Green formula:

$\int_{\Omega} div((b\cdot \nabla u)b)v = \int_{\partial\Omega} (b\cdot \nabla u)(b\cdot \vec{n})v - \int_{\Omega} (b\cdot \nabla u)(b\cdot \nabla v)$?

Comment: @Dadeslam: I think it is substantially the same